# Flutter + android receive data message on Firebase Cloud Messaging in Android

Tags: android, flutter, messaging

Accoding to https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages Flutter's firebase cloud notificaitons package cannot receive data messages without a notification when the app is terminated.

To bypass this i decided to write an android service to receive said messages and put them in an SQL Lite database on receive. Which can then be accessed by the flutter application.

I've registered the service in AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
  <service android:name=".NotificationService"
                android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Then i created NotificationsService.java as follows:

```
public class NotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d("Message", "received");
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
```

However when i receive a message on my test device the log is not recorded in the Debug log.
I also tried writing a String to a file when the message is received in cases where the app is terminated, still no joy.

Any ideas people?

Thanks, 
  Rob.

Comment: <https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs> suggests moving the intent filter to application and ditching service. Trying that now.

Comment: service needs to run and that's bound to the flutter app, any ideas?